# .NET MVC Deployment Options, Patches and Automatic updates

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have just moved from the world of LAMP SaaS to a MS-SQL Server, ASP.NET MVC 4.5.1 server-based application.  The application allows users to fill-out web-based forms, store data and generate .DOC and PDFs.

We use GIT for source code version control and CD-ROM distribution for the initial product installation on the client's premises. But we have difficulty figuring out how to push automatic software (new features, new forms, bug fixes) and database (ex. CRUD tax rates) updates. We like to offer MS-Windows style of updates with either the user initiating a fetch-and-apply or the software automatically checking if there are any updates.

Is there any software suites or packages that follow best practices and help us with this? I have been looking at OctopusDeploy, BuildMaster and PuppetChef but it seems that most of them focus on optimizing the internal development process rather than the client-pushing updates.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Greg